# adding an image from a different website in the following html snippet

Tags: html, image, embedded-resource

I'm using [FreeWebDesigner](http://www.freesitedesigner.com) to edit a certain website. Please excuse the clunkiness of the html snippet that I am discussing regarding my question. The following snippet would produce the results seen [here](http://www.fyrebyrdes.com/pb/wp_89fa4290.html?0.9821295458823442).

```
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><font face="Times New Roman"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #00ccff; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">Enjoy</span></b><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #3366ff; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"> a fun and affordable learning experience </span></b><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #00ccff; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">beyond the club level</span></b><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #3366ff; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><o:p></o:p></span></b></font></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #3366ff; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">Nov 6, 7, and 8, 2009<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #3366ff; FONT-SIZE: 17pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><o:p><font face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;</font></o:p></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><font face="Times New Roman"><v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" stroked="f" filled="f" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" o:preferrelative="t" o:spt="75" coordsize="21600,21600"><v:stroke joinstyle="miter"></v:stroke><v:formulas><v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"></v:f><v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"></v:f><v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"></v:f><v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"></v:f><v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"></v:f><v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"></v:f><v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"></v:f><v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"></v:f><v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"></v:f><v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"></v:f><v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"></v:f><v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"></v:f></v:formulas><v:path o:connecttype="rect" gradientshapeok="t" o:extrusionok="f"></v:path><o:lock aspectratio="t" v:ext="edit"></o:lock></v:shapetype><v:shape style="WIDTH: 337.5pt; HEIGHT: 299.25pt" id="_x0000_i1025" alt="" type="#_x0000_t75"><v:imagedata o:href="https://district13tm.sslpowered.com/images/tmlogocolor.gif" src="file:///C:\DOCUME~1\Stanley\LOCALS~1\Temp\msohtml1\01\clip_image001.gif"></v:imagedata></v:shape></font></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><span style="COLOR: #3366ff"><o:p><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;</font></o:p></span></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #3366ff; FONT-SIZE: 20pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">Fall 09 Conference<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: red; FONT-SIZE: 18pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">INVITES YOU!<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: red; FONT-SIZE: 18pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><o:p><font face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;</font></o:p></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: red; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">Capture the Imagination<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #ff6600; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">with the<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: green; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">World Champion of Public<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><font face="Times New Roman"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: green; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">Speaking</span></b><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #ff6600; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"> </span></b><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: #3366ff; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">and her coach</span></b><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: blue; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><o:p></o:p></span></b></font></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">At Fall 09 Conference<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><font face="Times New Roman">Grand Villa Casino and<o:p></o:p></font></span></b></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><font face="Times New Roman"><st1:place w:st="on"><st1:placename w:st="on"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">Conference</span></b></st1:placename><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"> <st1:placetype w:st="on">Center</st1:placetype></span></b></st1:place><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">,<o:p></o:p></span></b></font></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><font face="Times New Roman"><st1:place w:st="on"><st1:city w:st="on"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">Burnaby</span></b></st1:city><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">, <st1:state w:st="on">BC</st1:state></span></b></st1:place><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><o:p></o:p></span></b></font></p>
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: purple; FONT-SIZE: 15pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt"><o:p><font face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;</font></o:p></span></b></p>
<p style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">With less than $200 for the entire weekend from Friday night to Sunday, you can enjoy with your Toastmasters, friends and families</font></p>
<ul style="MARGIN-TOP: 0in" type="disc">
    <li style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1; tab-stops: list .5in" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">Great delicious food</font></li>
    <li style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1; tab-stops: list .5in" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">Humorous contests</font></li>
    <li style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1; tab-stops: list .5in" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">Table Topics contests</font></li>
    <li style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1; tab-stops: list .5in" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">Live music entertainment</font></li>
    <li style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1; tab-stops: list .5in" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">Dance lessons</font></li>
    <li style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt; mso-list: l0 level1 lfo1; tab-stops: list .5in" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">World Champion of Public Speaking and her mentor, a professional coach</font></li>
</ul>
<p style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 0.25in" class="MsoNormal"><o:p><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">&nbsp;</font></o:p></p>
<p style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal"><span style="COLOR: red"><font size="3"><font face="Times New Roman">Share our joy!<o:p></o:p></font></font></span></b></p>
<p style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">Come with a group of 10 @ </font><a href="http://www.d21fallconference.com/"><font size="3" face="Times New Roman">www.d21fallconference.com</font></a></p>
```

I would like to add an embedded picture right before "Fall 09 Conference" in the text from [here](http://www.toastmasters.org/Members/OfficerResources/DistrictOfficerResources/DistrictStationery/Logos/ColorHighRez.aspx), center-aligned. What would be the easiest method of achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You HTML code is very bad, have a lot of "Microsoft tag's", but dont worry about it.

try this:

```
<p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class="MsoNormal" align="center"><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;clear:both">
<span style="COLOR: #3366ff; FONT-SIZE: 20pt; mso-bidi-font-size: 12.0pt">
<font face="Times New Roman">Fall 09 Conference<o:p></o:p>
</font>
</span>
</b>
</p> 
<img src="images.extension" style="clear:both;">
```

Comment: I'm having problems aligning the image to be also center-justified. It would be great if I can get some tips on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: < img src="image.extension" style="margin:0 auto"> try
regards